# navigation after dispatchin action redux with react native

Tags: react-native, authentication, redux, react-redux, react-navigation-v5

I try to introduce authentication react native app with redux, after dispatching the login action.The code in the Login Screen:

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const auth = useSelector(state => state.authentication);

const onSubmit = (data: {email: string; password: string}) => {
  dispatch(loginUser(data));
  auth.isAuth && navigation.navigate('Home');
};
```

The code of action login is :

```js
export const loginUser = data => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: `${API_URl}/auth/login`,
      data,
    });
    dispatch({type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: res.data});    
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({type: GET_ERRORS, payload: error.response.data});
    dispatch({type: LOGIN_FAILED, payload: error.response.data});
  }
};
```

The code for reducer is above:

```js
 case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
 case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: payload.user,
        isAuth: true,
        message: null,
      };
```

I want to navigate to another screen 'Home' but this is not done for the first time after dispatching login action although I have verified that the state is changed :
[enter image description the console after press login button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iidz2.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `onSubmit`, which calls `loginUser`. At `loginUser` though, you have an API call which is async, which means that right after you call `loginUser`, `auth.isAuth` will always be false.

You need to make sure `auth.isAuth === true` on `componentDidMount` of your login screen, or use something like `redux-observable` to react to actions that are being dispatched and perform the navigation.

Comment: I try to use the verification of authentication and navigation inside useEffect with array of dependencies emty but the problem stilled.

Comment: Have a look at what the docs of react-navigation say regarding authentication flows: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/